# Prevent cut and paste from/to RDP client

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

Is there a way to ensure a windows remote desktop client does not have access to cut/paste from/to the host machine from the host OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to turn off clipboard redirection in group policy:

Start -> Run -> gpedit.msc

Then

Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Terminal Services -> Client/Server Data Redirection -> ***Do Not Allow Clipboard Redirection***