# Allow copy-paste into MS Remote Desktop, but not copy from there?

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a Microsoft Remote Desktop connecting to a server.

Is it possible to enable copy-pasting from my local computer into the remote windows, but disable it the other way round?

(this way it would be harder to export data from the remote machine)

Comment: Does [this](http://superuser.com/a/303214/270195) look like something you can try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature that enables the two-way communication is called Clipboard Redirection (the link in the comment shows how to disable this via GP). Unfortunately, what you are looking for can not be achieved with RDP because clipboard redirection only works in both directions: it synchronizes (or unifies) the local and remote clipboards.

What is the scenario that you are looking to enable - maybe there is another alternative?

/cd

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for asking. I have an RDP where copying from the remote should be forbidden for data security. The remote computer is not directly connected to the internet. I can set up a network connection to some extend. What solution would you suggest to copy snippets into the remote as painlessly as possible? (Critical ports are too sensitive however.)